# AWS Ruby lambda namespaced handler setting in AWS CDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a question about lambda function handler in `Ruby` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-handler.html. They say that you can namespace your function logic in a `modules` and `class`, like so:

```rb
module LambdaFunctions
  class ApiHandler
    def self.process(event:,context:)
      "Hello!"
    end
  end
end
```

and then in CDK the handler setting would be `source.LambdaFunctions::Handler.process`

```js
const apiProxyLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'apiProxyLambda', {
 runtime: lambda.Runtime.RUBY_2_7,
 handler: 'source.LambdaFunctions::Handler.process',
});
```

What if I wanted to define the entry point to `ApiHandler#process` instance method, like so?

```rb
module LambdaFunctions
  class ApiHandler
    def process(event:,context:)
      do_some_stuff
    end
  
    private
    
    def do_some_stuff
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I suspect that the correct reference to the instance method in this case would be `source.LambdaFunctions::Handler#process`. Does anyone know if this is correct? If this is possible, the my question is, how would lambda 'know' that it needs to instantiate my class first

```rb
handler = LambdaFunctions::ApiHandler.new
```

and then call `handler.process(event: event, context: context)`?

Comment: *"how would lambda 'know' that it needs to instantiate my class first"*, It would not. It appears that you would need to use so called "class methods" (which are really just instance methods where the receiver is a class). Is there a reason why you would need to avoid this? If so (and I have no idea how lambdas work) maybe you could use `'source.LambdaFunctions::Handler.new.process'`?

Comment: It's just Ruby convention, no other specific reason. Good call about `'source.LambdaFunctions::Handler.new.process'`. Maybe they pass `event` and `context` to whatever you indicate as the entrypoint to your lambda so that would be a good reasoning. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It is not a ruby convention to create an instance (via `XYZ.new`) of a class to perform this functionality which is why I asked. A class itself by declaration alone is already an instance of the class `Class`, it can have it's own instance variables, its own methods, etc. It appears based on the documentation you provided this is the preferred method of execution but feel free to try the alternative and see what happens, at least you'll know if its possible.